# Android 4.0 ICS Webview with “Unknown chromium error: -324”

Tags: android, webview, webkit

I coding a Browser use WebView in Android 4.0 ICS.
But when I access some website，a error occurred.

I Override the `onReceivedError` method in WebViewClient,
and I print the logcat.

```
08-28 09:22:00.549: D/chromium(22081): Unknown chromium error: -324

08-28 09:22:32.658: E/sky-mobi(22081): errorCode:-1 description:A network error occurred。failingUrl:https://172.16.28.5/portal/logon.htm

08-28 09:22:32.705: W/Web Console(22081): The page at “https://172.16.28.5/portal/logon.htm” displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.

08-28 09:22:32.705: W/Web Console(22081):  at null:1
```

I test the URL with Android 2.3.3 ,and it totally work fine。

Answer (score 7):

We've run into this problem on multiple occasions and each time it appears to be completely random. No changes to the Webview, no changes to the html/css/js content, nothing. The only solution we've ever found is to reset the device that's experiencing the problem and then, as if by magic, the problem is gone on reboot. Our best guess is that repeatedly building and debugging on a device can result in these types of corrupt installations as we've noticed other phantom debug issues coinciding with these types of errors.

Hope this helps anyone else who experiences a similar problem.

Comment: im getting this error too. it also appears randomly for me and is very frustrating, someone must be able to get to the bottom of what is causing this, perhaps we should enter a bug into the android bug tracking database?


this page seems to be the one of the only pages acknowledging this bug on the web. i tried searching the android bug tracking database but couldnt find anything there. though im new to it, so not exactly sure how it works...

I have overridden the onReceivedError method for the webview, but it doesnt actually trap this error. I only find out about the error in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try http instead of https